# How can I create a proper Collection in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I am trying to convert a large 3 dimensioned Array into a series of class modules. I have each next class stored as an array in the previous class. It goes like Brand -> Products -> Lots.

I have successfully created this interaction and can access them by name like:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim MyBrand As Brand
    Set MyBrand = New Brand
    MyBrand.Name = "Company1"
    MyBrand.AddProduct "Shoes"
    MyBrand.Products("Shoes").AddLot "240502"
    MsgBox MyBrand.Products("Shoes").Lots(0) 'Correctly Displays "240502"
End Sub
```

But then I wanted to create an object group that can save multiple `Brand` objects and access them like `Brands("Company1")`.

If I used an array inside a class module, I'd end up with `Brands.Brand("Company1")`.
If I used a `Collection`, I'd have to use indexes like `Brands(1)`.

Is there a way to create a proper object group so that I can mimic the syntax of groups like Application.Workbooks and refer to members by Name?

Comment: You can use a `Scripting.Dictionary` with `Name` as the key.

Comment: Why not use `Collection.Add item, key` and then get element by key?

Comment: They can have KEYS?!

Comment: If you have the possibility of duplicate keys I suggest a dictionary it has a built in `.exists()`

Comment: Yes, just trying out Collections with keys and it seems like Dictionary is superior. I get an error when I try to check `MyCollection("New Name") is Nothing`. Which means I cant test it like I can with `MyDict.Exists("New Name")`.

Comment: Good overview here - http://codevba.com/help/collection.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams If you want to, add your first comment as an answer and I'll give you the check mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Scripting.Dictionary` with `Name` as the key:

```vb
Sub test()
    
    Dim MyBrand As Brand
    Dim Brands As Object
    
    Set Brands = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set MyBrand = New Brand
    MyBrand.Name = "Company1"
    MyBrand.AddProduct "Shoes"
    MyBrand.Products("Shoes").AddLot "240502"
    
    Brands.Add MyBrand.Name, MyBrand
    
    MsgBox Brands("Company1").Products("Shoes").Lots(0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

A lot of the magic behind custom collections depends on hidden attributes that you cannot edit from within the VBE; you need to export (and remove from the project when prompted) the class module, edit its magic member attributes in Notepad/Notepad++, save changes, and then re-import the module into the project.

That's obviously tedious and error-prone, but there's a (much) better way.

In order to support this:

```vb
Set shoesProduct = MyBrand.Products("Shoes")
```

You can define `Products` as a `Dictionary` and call it a day, but then *encapsulation* as a concept is... well, taking a beating here (whether the internal collection is a `Dictionary`, a `Collection`, or a .NET `ArrayList` should typically be an *implementation detail* that the rest of the code doesn't need to care about).

I suspect the `Brand` class has too many responsibilities and "is" the product collection; best practices would be to have the `Brand.Products` property defined as follows:

```vb
Public Property Get Products() As Products
```

So you'll want to have a `Products` class (very much like the `Workbook.Worksheets` and `Workbook.Sheets` properties both return a `Sheets` collection object) that encapsulates a private, module-level `VBA.Collection` field (possibly keyed, but you can't access or iterate the keys of a collection).

The `Products` custom collection class needs an `Item` *default property* (the name `Item` is a convention); the implementation just pulls the item from the private encapsulated `Collection`:

```vb
'@DefaultMember
Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As Variant) As Product
    Set Item = ThePrivateCollection.Item(Index)
End Property
```

If you are using [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com), this `@DefaultMember` annotation/comment is going to trigger an inspection result about the annotation and the corresponding hidden attribute(s) being "out of sync"; right-click that inspection result and pick "Adjust attribute values" to have Rubberduck generate the hidden code for you and deal with the annoying export/delete-edit-reimport cycle.

Otherwise, you'll want to manually edit the hidden `VB_UserMemId` member attribute that makes it the class' *default member*:

```vb
Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As Variant) As Product
    Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set Item = ThePrivateCollection.Item(Index)
End Property
```

And with that, `MyBrand.Products("Shoes")` becomes equivalent to `MyBrand.Products.Item("Shoes")`.

Perhaps you want to iterate all the products in the collection, too?

```vb
For Each Product In MyBrand.Products
    Debug.Print Product.Name
Next
```

In order to do this, you need a special "enumerator" member that forwards the enumerator from the encapsulated collection:

```vb
'@Enumerator
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = ThePrivateCollection.[_NewEnum]
End Property
```

Again, Rubberduck annotations greatly simplify doing this, but everything Rubberduck does, you can also do manually if you like:

```vb
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = ThePrivateCollection.[_NewEnum]
End Sub
```

And now `For Each` iteration works for your custom object collection!

If a `Lot` was more than just a `String` value (i.e. an actual object type), then the `Product` class could use a `Lots` custom collection too - but since a `Lot` is really just a `String` value (or is it?), then `Product` can simply encapsulate a `Dictionary`, and have a `Lots` property that exposes the `Items` array:

```vb
Public Property Get Lots() As Variant
    Lots = ThePrivateLotsDictionary.Items
End Property
```

Note, that's simpler than using a `Collection`, because with a collection you'd need to iterate it and copy each item to an array in order to return the items without exposing the collection itself (exposing `Lots() As Collection` makes the `AddLot` member completely redundant).

As for the `Brands` collection itself, heed [Tim Williams' advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67794487/1188513) and use a `Dictionary` data structure.

Comment: When I first saw your answer I had to set a reminder to come back after gaining more experience with class modules.  After half a month of study, I feel like I'm still only halfway to being able to comprehend the wisdom contained within it. Thank you for the great answer, I'll have to come back again after studying some more.

Comment: Welcome to the club. Matt's answers are almost always like this. I have to read and study them at least 3 times, and I’ve been following him in SO for almost 5 years. I suggest that you go and grab a copy of rubberduck and your life will be 10 times easier learning about VBA and OOP. His blog is also a great source of knowledge around this topic